# How to write this recursive groupBy function in Scala

Tags: scala, recursion, types

Recently I have come across a very useful **groupBy** function that Groovy has made available on Iterable:

```
public static Map groupBy(Iterable self, List<Closure> closures)
```

Which you can use to perform recursive **groupBy** on Lists and even Maps [see example by mrhaki here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/groovy-goodness-groupby-with-multiple.html)

I would like to write a function that does the same in Scala. But having just started my Scala journey, I am kind of lost on how I should going about defining and implementing this method. Especially the **generics** side of the functions and return type on this method's signature are way beyond my level.

I would need more experienced Scala developers to help me out here.

Is this following signature totally wrong or am I in the ball park?

```
def groupBy[A, K[_]](src: List[A], fs: Seq[(A) ⇒ K[_]]): Map[K[_], List[A]]
```

Also, how would I implement the recursion with the correct types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simple multigroup implementation:

```
implicit class GroupOps[A](coll: Seq[A]) {
  def groupByKeys[B](fs: (A => B)*): Map[Seq[B], Seq[A]] =
    coll.groupBy(elem => fs map (_(elem)))
}

val a = 1 to 20

a.groupByKeys(_ % 3, _ % 2) foreach println
```

If you really need some recursive type you'll need a wrapper:

```
sealed trait RecMap[K, V]

case class MapUnit[K, V](elem: V) extends RecMap[K, V] {
  override def toString = elem.toString()
}
case class MapLayer[K, V](map: Map[K, RecMap[K, V]]) extends RecMap[K, V] {
  override def toString = map.toString()
}
```

out definition changes to:

```
implicit class GroupOps[A](coll: Seq[A]) {
  def groupByKeys[B](fs: (A => B)*): Map[Seq[B], Seq[A]] =
    coll.groupBy(elem => fs map (_(elem)))

  def groupRecursive[B](fs: (A => B)*): RecMap[B, Seq[A]] = fs match {
    case Seq() => MapUnit(coll)
    case f +: fs => MapLayer(coll groupBy f mapValues {_.groupRecursive(fs: _*)})
  }
}
```

and  `a.groupRecursive(_ % 3, _ % 2)` yield something more relevant to question

And finally i rebuild domain definition from referred article:

```
case class User(name: String, city: String, birthDate: Date) {
  override def toString = name
}

implicit val date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(_: String)
val month = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM").format (_:Date)

val users = List(
  User(name = "mrhaki", city = "Tilburg"  , birthDate = "1973-9-7"),
  User(name = "bob"   , city = "New York" , birthDate = "1963-3-30"),
  User(name = "britt" , city = "Amsterdam", birthDate = "1980-5-12"),
  User(name = "kim"   , city = "Amsterdam", birthDate = "1983-3-30"),
  User(name = "liam"  , city = "Tilburg"  , birthDate = "2009-3-6")
)
```

now we can write

```
users.groupRecursive(_.city, u => month(u.birthDate))
```

and get

> Map(Tilburg -> Map(Mar -> List(liam), Sep -> List(mrhaki)), New York
>   -> Map(Mar -> List(bob)), Amsterdam -> Map(Mar -> List(kim), May -> List(britt)))

Comment: Amazing! Had no idea about recursive types. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I decided add another answer, due to fully different approach.

You could, actually get non-wrapped properly typed maps with huge workarounds. I not very good at this, so it by the chance could be simplified.

Trick - is to create Sequence of typed functions, which is lately producing multi-level map using `type classes` and `type path` approach.

So here is the solution

```
sealed trait KeySeq[-V] {
  type values
}

case class KeyNil[V]() extends KeySeq[V] {
  type values = Seq[V]
}

case class KeyCons[K, V, Next <: KeySeq[V]](f: V => K, next: Next)
                                           (implicit ev: RecGroup[V, Next]) extends KeySeq[V] {
  type values = Map[K, Next#values]

  def #:[K1](f: V => K1) = new KeyCons[K1, V, KeyCons[K, V, Next]](f, this)
}

trait RecGroup[V, KS <: KeySeq[V]] {
  def group(seq: Seq[V], ks: KS): KS#values
}

implicit def groupNil[V]: RecGroup[V, KeyNil[V]] = new RecGroup[V, KeyNil[V]] {
  def group(seq: Seq[V], ks: KeyNil[V]) = seq
}

implicit def groupCons[K, V, Next <: KeySeq[V]](implicit ev: RecGroup[V, Next]): RecGroup[V, KeyCons[K, V, Next]] =
  new RecGroup[V, KeyCons[K, V, Next]] {
    def group(seq: Seq[V], ks: KeyCons[K, V, Next]) = seq.groupBy(ks.f) mapValues (_ groupRecursive ks.next)
  }



implicit def funcAsKey[K, V](f: V => K): KeyCons[K, V, KeyNil[V]] =
  new KeyCons[K, V, KeyNil[V]](f, KeyNil[V]())

implicit class GroupOps[V](coll: Seq[V]) {
  def groupRecursive[KS <: KeySeq[V]](ks: KS)(implicit g: RecGroup[V, KS]) =
    g.group(coll, ks)
}
```

key functions are composed via `#:` right-associative operator

so if we define

```
def mod(m:Int) = (x:Int) => x % m
def even(x:Int) = x % 2 == 0
```

then

```
1 to 30 groupRecursive (even _ #: mod(3)   #: mod(5) )
```

would yield proper `Map[Boolean,Map[Int,Map[Int,Int]]]` !!!

and if from previous question we would like to

```
users.groupRecursive(((u:User)=> u.city(0)) #: ((u:User) => month(u.birthDate)))
```

We are building `Map[Char,Map[String,User]]` !